# Drupal database connection

Tags: database, drupal-7

Is it necessary to connect to Drupal database in order to fetch something from database?

And if I already have Drupal installed, would I still need to make connection in any template file in order to fetch data?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Drupal, you really should abstract from the database as much as possible and use Drupal's framework to get the data you need.

If you're using a template, a lot of data is already made available at the template itself - usually there's a good description of what data is available on the comments at the top of the template. If you need additional data not available, the recommended course of action is to make that data available to the template using the appropriate hooks (form_alter, view_alter, node_view_alter and so forth).

Templates shouldn't worry about getting the data, they should only focus on how to display the data available - similar principle to MVC where the View (template in Drupal) worries about presentation, not on the business logic or data abstractions.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanku for your reply, actually I have to fetch the taxonomy tree from database with all of its children and parents

Comment: You might want to have a look at something like the taxonomy_get_tree function then. Drupal provides several different functions to interact with taxonomies that might be helpful.

Comment: `$vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load("product sub categories");
$terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vocabulary);` ,here "product sub categories" is my vocabulary, I want to print the whole tree but didnt get any result from this

Comment: Don't think that's the right machine name of the vocabulary (can't have spaces). Edit the vocabulary through Drupal front end and you'll see the real machine name.. That should fix it.

Comment: oh yeah sorry for that this was "product_sub_categories", but now it showing error pointing to taxonomy.module file in given lines `if (!isset($children[$vid])) {
    $children[$vid] = array();
    $parents[$vid] = array();
    $terms[$vid] = array();`, do you have any idea about this ??